# Breeze: How to make use of entity constructor code on server?

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

The question could also look like "Why is my initialization code of object in server not working?".

For example,

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public Order()
    {
        Quantity = 10;
    }
}
```

From debugger, I can see the contructor is called and Quantity is set, however, it is not taking effect. I have to set Quantity on client side after the entity is created to make it work.

Is there a way to make the initialization on server work? By the way, my project is in Angular/Breeze/EF.

UPDATE: As I dig a little further, I believe, this is the general "issue" with Breeze that the server side change must be added to so-called entityInfo.OriginalValueMap, otherwise, its change is not saved. If true, how can work around this limitation because I have a lot default values I'd like to set on server?

This is how I create my entity:

```
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager("breeze/breeze");
manager.enableSaveQueuing(true);

    function _createEntity(entityName) {
        return manager.createEntity(entityName);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with its not working? When you are creating a new instance of Order isnt it 10? Its just the default value.

Comment: Not working means I still see quantity = 0 on client.

Answer (score 2):

Setting any initialization code on the server in the model constructor won't work simply because the JavaScript client doesn't know anything about the C# constructor code on the server.

The DefaultValueAttribute is only honored when you're constructing a Model-First metadata. It is unfortunately ignored by EF when constructing a Code-First model metadata.

I suggest that you see [Breeze - Create Entity on Server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20338591/breeze-create-entity-on-server-side) for how another user solves a similar situation by creating a "create Endpoint" on the server that basically returns a new entity with default values set.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create a constructor to set default values.
Just add the default value data annotation to any property you wish to set its default value:

```
[DefaultValue(10)]
public int Quantity { get; set; }
```

Also, consider not to initialize the Quantity when creating an entity at the client side.

Comment: This would be great. However, how comes it doesn't work for me either. What did I miss?

Comment: @miliu If you can see the order.qty value with 10 at client `console.log(order.qty)`, then it should work. That's how I set my default values. How do you create the entity at client? Code?

Comment: please see my update above for how I create my entity.